# how to write a macro that will append text to a partial function name to create complete function name

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm trying to figure out how to write a C Preprocessor macro that can accept a partial function name and a piece of text to append to the function name along with a set of arguments to create the actual function name and function call. The idea is to combine the first two macro arguments to create a function name and then add the rest of the macro arguments as arguments for the function name created.

So I want to achieve the following:

```
MACRO(foo, postfix, ...)
----> foo_postfix(__VA_ARGS__)
```

For instance if I have several C functions, `func_test1()` and `func_test2()` and `func_test3()` then I want to be able to use the macro to specify `func` as the first argument and `test1` as the second argument so that the macro will create a function name of `func_test1()`, or to specify `func` as the first argument and `test2` as the second argument so that the macro will create a function name of `func_test2`.

or something like

```
#define MACRO(foo,postfix,...)  "macro to combine foo and postfix into actual function name"
```

and then I could use this macro like

```
MACRO(func, test1, a, b, c);  // will create func_test1(a, b, c);
MACRO(func, test2, i, x);     // will create func_test2(i, x);
```

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @EJP I'm trying to call different functions based on compiler flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `##` in the macro to concatenate the two parameters as strings. So if your macro is

```
MACRO(foo, postfix, ...)
```

you could define it like this

```
MACRO(foo, postfix, ...) foo##_##postfix(__VA_ARGS__)
                              ^^^ adds an underscore in the middle. Don't include if you
                                 don't want the underscore.
```

to concatenate `foo` and `postfix` with an underscore in between.

Be careful when using arguments that are macros with these types of macros. The argument is pasted without undergoing macro expansion so doing `MACRO(foo, MYMACRO, ~)` will expand to `foo_MYMACRO()` instead of the value of `MYMACRO`.

Comment: what if postfix is defined before? example: `#define postfix ABC` -- I used the pattern and it is not working properly

Comment: Tokens are concatenated before outside macros are checked for replacement. To do what you want to do you have to use multiple levels of macros. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d8dd00f9e278e09) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

The C preprocessor allows you to use `##` to "glue" tokens together.

This means that

```
#define MACRO(x, y) x ## _ ## y
MACRO(foo, postfix)
```

will be turned into

```
foo_postfix
```